# How to determine the minimum number to totally break a connected rings?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

It's a question on [checkio - Break Rings](https://checkio.org/mission/break-rings/), but I only can use a bad way with O(n*2^n) complexity by testing all possible break ways and find the minimum one.

**The problem:
A blacksmith gave his apprentice a task, ordering them to make a selection of rings. The apprentice is not yet skilled in the craft and as a result of this, some (to be honest, most) of rings came out connected together. Now he’s asking for your help separating the rings and deciding how to break enough rings to free so as to get the maximum number of rings possible.**

All of the rings are numbered and you are told which of the rings are connected. This information is given as a sequence of sets. Each set describes the connected rings. For example: {1, 2} means that the 1st and 2nd rings are connected. You should count how many rings we need to break to get the maximum of separate rings. Each of the rings are numbered in a range from 1 to N, where N is total quantity of rings.

https://static.checkio.org/media/task/media/0d98b24304034e2e9017ba00fc51f6e3/example-rings.svg

example-rings

(sorry I don't know how to change the svg in mac to a photo.)

In the above image you can see the connections: ({1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{4,5},{4,6},{6,5}). The optimal solution here would be to break 3 rings, making 3 full and separate rings. So the result is 3.

**Input: Information about the connected rings as a tuple of sets with integers.**

**Output: The number of rings to break as an integer.**

It works only when the test case is small so it is not practical(I guess it even can't pass the test)

```
from functools import reduce
import copy

def break_rings(rings):
    max_ring = max(reduce(set.union,rings))
    rings = list(rings)
    possible_set = [list(bin(i)[2:].rjust(max_ring,'0')) for i in range(2**max_ring)]
    possible_set = [list(map(int,j)) for j in possible_set]
    min_result = max_ring
    for test_case in possible_set:
        tmp = copy.copy(rings)
        tmp2 = copy.copy(rings)
        for index, value in enumerate(test_case):
            if value:
                for set_connect in tmp:
                    if index+1 in set_connect and set_connect in tmp2:
                        tmp2.remove(set_connect)
        if not tmp2:
            min_result = min(sum(test_case),min_result)
    return min_result
```

So, I think it must thinking about the algorithm about the graph, but i just don't know what kind of problem I am facing.

Can you help me improve the algorithm?

Thank you for looking this problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of this as a type of graph problem called [vertex cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover).

Draw a graph with a vertex for each ring, and an edge for each connection, i.e. each pair of joined rings.

Your task is to disconnect the rings with minimum breakages.  A connection is broken if the ring at either edge is broken.  In other words, you need to choose a set of rings (vertices) such that every connection (edge) is incident to one to the chosen rings.

This is exactly the vertex cover problem.

Unfortunately, vertex cover is NP-complete so there is not any non-exponential algorithm currently known.

I would recommend improving the speed of your algorithm by rejecting bad cases earlier.  For example, use a backtracking algorithm that decides for each ring whether to break it or not.  If you chose to not break it, you can immediately conclude a lot of other rings must be broken.

Comment: Thank you, it exactly the vertex cover, and after reading several pdf about the pseudo code and java implementation, the time is cut into acceptable span.

Comment: @ljy Do you have the final code and the references you came across? Thanks.